# How to get variable's value in split_clients NGINX

Tags: nginx

I'm using `[split_clients]` and it works perfectly in most cases.

Ref: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html

`split_clients` returns a literally string for further use.

But now, I need returned string contains a variable, like this:

**`http` context**:

```
split_clients "${remote_addr}${http_user_agent}${date_gmt}" $my_variable {
    20%     https://example.com/fixed_string/another_fixed_string;
    *       https://example.com/$1/another_fixed_string;
}
```

**`server` context**:

```
location ~ ^/abc/(.*) {
   rewrite ^/abc/(.*) $my_variable redirect;
}
```

When I visit `https://example.org/abc/something`, it redirect to `https://example.com/$1/another_fixed_string` with `$1` is a literally string in URL.

My expectation is `$1` acts as a variable, and its value is `something`, then redirect to `https://example.com/something/another_fixed_string`

How to implement it?

Comment: Is there any way to replace in string, something like `str_replace("$1", $1, $my_variable)`?. This would work if it's feasible.

Comment: Combine split_clients with a map?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille thank you, it works. You save my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gerard H. Pille suggested, using `map` can solve this issue.

**`http` context**:

```
split_clients "${remote_addr}${http_user_agent}${date_gmt}" $my_variable {
    20%     0;
    *       1;
}

map $my_variable $my_url {
   #default you can also set the default value

   0     https://example.com/fixed_string/another_fixed_string;
   1     https://example.com/$1/another_fixed_string;
}
```

**`server` context**:

```
location ~ ^/abc/(.*) {
   rewrite ^/abc/(.*) $my_url redirect;
}
```